# Slide Down and Slide Up Toggle

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to build a slide down menu with four headings. Once I click on a heading its list has to slide down and slide back up once clicked again. I could do this only with all the lists, I mean once I click any heading all the list slide at same time. Could you please help to make each list which belongs to heading to appear once clicked. Thanks.

HTML

```
<nav>
    <ul>
          <li class="menu-block">heading1
            <ul>
            <li><a href="">item</a></li>
            <li><a href="">item</a></li>
            <li><a href="">item</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-block">heading2
            <ul>
            <li><a href="">item</a></li>
            <li><a href="">item</a></li>
            <li><a href="">item</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-block">heading3
            <ul>
            <li><a href="">item</a></li>
            <li><a href="">item</a></li>
            <li><a href="">item</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-block">heading4
            <ul>
            <li><a href="">item</a></li>
            <li><a href="">item</a></li>
            <li><a href="">item</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
nav{
    position:fixed;
    right: 0;
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
nav ul:first-child{
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width:30%;
    background: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
nav .menu-block li{
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    text-align: left;
    display: none;
}
```

JQuery

```
$(".menu-block").click(function(){
    $(this).find('nav .menu-block li').slideDown(500);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find the `li`s inside the clicked `li`. Besides, you might want to use `slideToggle` for this purpose:

```
$(".menu-block").click(function(){
    $(this).find('li').slideToggle(500);
});
```

Demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/q2gzamg6/

PS. You need to work on your css style definition here.

Answer (score 0):

Use this way:

```
$(".menu-block").click(function(){
    $(this).find('ul').slideDown(500);
});
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  $(".menu-block").click(function(){
    $(this).find('ul').slideDown(500);
  });
});
```

```css
nav{
  position:fixed;
  right: 0;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
nav ul:first-child{
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width:30%;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
nav .menu-block li{
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  text-align: left;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="menu-block">heading1
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="">item</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-block">heading2
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="">item</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-block">heading3
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="">item</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-block">heading4
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="">item</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I tried this way and this did not work as well. The next solution did exactly what I wanted. Thanks anyway :)